# How to : gcloud Snapshot MariaDB Galera Node?

Tags: backup

How to do a gcloud snapshot of Mariadb Galera Node for backup and restore ? I heard of people talking about gcloud snapshots and nowhere explains the full process of doing it. Kindly delight with the information please.

> Is that possible to use gcloud snapshot for this Mariadb Galera nodes ?
>   If yea, how to do it without downtime in production ?

Comment: It would be tricky because even if gcloud snapshorts where consistent (I've no evidence either way, but it would be a necessary restore criteria), you would need to identify the position of the snapshot and restore from that point forward. Might be possible when a node is writing a binlog and sync_binlog=1. The lack of mapping between [Galera GTIDs and MariaDB gtids](https://lists.launchpad.net/maria-discuss/msg05356.html) was the point of a recent contention. If you get stuck implementing it because of MariaDB/Galera, write a [JIRA issue](https://jira.mariadb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).